# phpMyAdmin, get a list of user email addess that don't exists in another table

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin, how do I get a list of all user from the table `users` column `mail`  that don't exist in the table `commerce_order` column `mail`. I only want to get a list of user that have NOT placed an order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
select mail from users where mail NOT IN (select mail from commerce_order)
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is :

```
select mail from users where mail NOT IN (select mail from commerce_order)
```